# No module named ttkwidgets

Tags: python, tkinter, frontend

Hello all: I am trying to use an autocomplete library from tkinter for an application. I was referencing this website: https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-autocomplete/

It told me to pip install Autocomplete, pillow (previously installed) and ttkwidgets(previously installed)

Copied and pasted the code , but when I ran it: I get a ModuleNotFoundError , saying no module named "ttkwidgets"

not sure what this issue is.

Would appreciate the help/next steps

[image]

Comment: You should generally not run `tkinter` programs from an `IPython` notebook. Save them to a file and run that.

Comment: hi there, yep, when running it on command prompt, it worked. Not sure why, but thank you!